# jQuery upload fails only on big files?

Tags: php, jquery, html, upload

I want to upload mp3 files with jQuery. Everything works fine on normal tracks. But if I want to upload some mixes, which are big files > 100MB, the upload fails.

This is my function for uploading:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                       

    $('#upFile').on('change', function() {
       $('#btnSubmit').fadeIn();
    });

     $('#uploadForm').submit(function(e) {  

         if($('#upFile').val()) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $('#btnSubmit').fadeOut();
            $('#progress-div').fadeIn();

            $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 

                beforeSubmit: function() {
                  $("#progress-bar").width('0%');
                },  

                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {    
                    $("#progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                    $("#progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-status">' + percentComplete +' %</div>')
                }, 

                success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) { 
                    $('#progress-div').fadeOut(function() {
                        //$("#progress-bar").width('0%');
                        //$("#progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-status">0 %</div>');
                        var obj = JSON.parse(responseText);                                                                          
                        if(obj.success == '1') {                                             
                            window.location.replace("./player");
                        } else {                                             
                            alert(obj.error);
                        }                                      

                    });

                },                                
                resetForm: true 
            }); 
            return false; 
        }
    });
});
```

What could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

After you have made sure you have enough storage space for the upload, check your `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini file. On the command line, type `php -i | grep upload_max_filesize` or create a secret.php file containing only

```
<php phpinfo();
```

or

```
<php echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
```

and look for `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: I have set everything up, but still same effect..  I think I'll try out a other uploader. lets see if it really is a server-issue

Answer (score 0):

edit your php.ini file and set:

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 120M
post_max_size = 150M
```

and restart apache.